# Faster way of reading number of lines in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to open a file, and count the number of lines there are in the file.

The code I am using for this is:

```py
def line_Count(x):
    with open(x,'r') as iFile:  # Open passed in file
        lines = iFile.readlines() # Read each line in the file
        line_Count = len(lines) # Count the number of lines
        return line_Count       # Return the line count
```

This works fine for small amounts of data (10k lines in 0.073 seconds).

However, for large files (1m lines), it is taking more than 15 minutes to complete.

Is there a faster way of completing the task?

The previous example is from more than 5 years ago, and some of the solutions have been deprecated since.

Comment: The crucial difference between your attempt and the linked question is that you *allocate memory for each line in the file*, thus keeping the entire file in memory. If you use `iFile` as a generator you only allocate one line at a time.

Comment: @CDJB the linked example crashes the machine after about 30 seconds. Some error about memory allocation.

Comment: @CDJB So which was the best solution in that link. I read all the solution , but they are from 2009 to latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using xreadlines (since you're dealing with big files) might give you a boost in Python2:

```
count = 0
for line in open(file_path).xreadlines(): count += 1
```

Or since you're using Python 3 using a generator might be less memory intensive:

```
count = sum(1 for i in open(file_path, 'rb'))
```

Or

```
def blocks(files, size=65536):
    while True:
        b = files.read(size)
        if not b: break
        yield b

with open(file_path, "r",encoding="utf-8",errors='ignore') as f:
    print (sum(bl.count("\n") for bl in blocks(f)))
```

Lastly you could "cheat" and use subprocess:

```
int(subprocess.check_output("wc -l " + file_path).split()[0])
```

Comment: Getting the following error when trying this: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'xreadlines'

Comment: Didnt see you're using python3, that is deprecated. Will update code.

Comment: Updated with more alternatives.

Comment: The second option solved it faster than current code. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! Wish you a nice continuation on your project :)